# Сокрытие версии tomcat при ошибке 404

Tags: java, безопасность, tomcat

Всем привет! Будучи неавторизованным пользователем - отправляем пустой запрос. В ответ получаем 404 и версию сервера. Как не отображать версию tomcat здесь?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Если стоит цель именно скрыть версию, то в папке `<TOMCAT HOME>\lib` создайте директорию `org\apache\catalina\util`, в которой создайте файл `ServerInfo.properties` с содержимым следующего вида:

```
server.info=
```

После перезапуска Томката версия исчезнет со страницы с ошибкой.